# Get parent category link

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the parent category link - this is my code but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
<?php
$taxonomyName = "equipment_categories";
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   
echo '<div class="subcats"><a class="subcatseach" href="' . $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . '">All Equipment</a>';
foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<a class="subcatseach" href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';  
    }
}
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try using `'child_of' => $pterm->term_id` instead of `'parent' => $pterm->term_id` in line 6